# how to add display images and sort from newest uploaded

Tags: android, image, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have fork from github this source code
https://github.com/quocnguyenvan/food-sqlite-demo

I need some help here
How to add display image in full screen? If we are in food list and click an image, the image will show at full screen

And one more, how to add sorting file? So the newest uploaded will be at the top of the list, thanks for helping me, i need this for my office

======================================================

## here is my code

FoodList class

```
public class FoodList extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<Food> list;
    FoodListAdapter adapter = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.food_list_activity);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new FoodListAdapter(this, R.layout.food_items, list);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // get all data from sqlite
        Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");
        list.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String price = cursor.getString(2);
            byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);

            list.add(new Food(name, price, image, id));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

                CharSequence[] items = {"Preview", "Download"};
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(FoodList.this);

                dialog.setTitle("Choose an action");
                dialog.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        if (item == 0) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageDisplay.class);
                            i.putExtra("id", position);
                            startActivity(i);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You click on " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"you download " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
                //return true;
            }
        });

        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

                CharSequence[] items = {"Update", "Delete"};
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(FoodList.this);

                dialog.setTitle("Choose an action");
                dialog.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        if (item == 0) {
                            // update
                            Cursor c = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id FROM FOOD");
                            ArrayList<Integer> arrID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                            while (c.moveToNext()){
                                arrID.add(c.getInt(0));
                            }
                            // show dialog update at here
                            showDialogUpdate(FoodList.this, arrID.get(position));

                        } else {
                            // delete
                            Cursor c = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id FROM FOOD");
                            ArrayList<Integer> arrID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                            while (c.moveToNext()){
                                arrID.add(c.getInt(0));
                            }
                            showDialogDelete(arrID.get(position));
                        }
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    ImageView imageViewFood;
    private void showDialogUpdate(Activity activity, final int position){

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.update_food_activity);
        dialog.setTitle("Update");

        imageViewFood = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFood);
        final EditText edtName = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        final EditText edtPrice = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edtPrice);
        Button btnUpdate = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

        // set width for dialog
        int width = (int) (activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * 0.95);
        // set height for dialog
        int height = (int) (activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels * 0.7);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
        dialog.show();

        imageViewFood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // request photo library
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        FoodList.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        888
                );
            }
        });

        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.updateData(
                            edtName.getText().toString().trim(),
                            edtPrice.getText().toString().trim(),
                            MainActivity.imageViewToByte(imageViewFood),
                            position
                    );
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update successfully!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (Exception error) {
                    Log.e("Update error", error.getMessage());
                }
                updateFoodList();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showDialogDelete(final int idFood){
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialogDelete = new AlertDialog.Builder(FoodList.this);

        dialogDelete.setTitle("Warning!!");
        dialogDelete.setMessage("Are you sure you want to this delete?");
        dialogDelete.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                try {
                    MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.deleteData(idFood);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Delete successfully!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
                }
                updateFoodList();
            }
        });

        dialogDelete.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialogDelete.show();
    }

    private void updateFoodList(){
        // get all data from sqlite
        Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");
        list.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String name = cursor.getString(1);
            String price = cursor.getString(2);
            byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);

            list.add(new Food(name, price, image, id));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if(requestCode == 888){
            if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 888);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You don't have permission to access file location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(requestCode == 888 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                imageViewFood.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

i want to display image in fullscreen when user click on it

here is my DisplayImage class

```
    public class ImageDisplay extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.imagedisplay);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageView imageViewFood = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullimage);
        imageViewFood.setImageResource(position);
    }
}
```

is it correct code ? please help me, thanks

Comment: Is that one question? It looks like two.

Comment: If it is a single question it seems unclear.

Comment: Can you give more details on the one programming problem you have? can you reduce it to a managable size, which can be posted here as a [mcve]? You describe that images are shown in full size. Then you ask how to add an image in full screen. That needs more explanation of what the problem is.

Comment: Ok i just need to preview it's image on fullscreen when user click on it, edited my first page

Comment: If that is an answer to my question, then please rephrase it. I do not get your meaning.

Comment: ok i already add my detail in my first post, please help